# Unable to pass data from Service to a Component in Angular

Tags: angular, post, get

I am trying to pass data from my service to my component but unable to do so. Below is the code from service and component:

**authService.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import{Http, RequestOptions,Headers} from '@angular/http'
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { URLSearchParams,Response } from '@angular/http';


 @Injectable()

  export class AuthenticationService
    {
         constructor(private http: Http) { }
         username:string = 'Admin';
         password:string='livelink';  
         result :any;

        login() 
         {

           let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
           urlSearchParams.append('Username', this.username);
           urlSearchParams.append('Password', this.password);

    return this.http.post('http://localhost/otcs/cs.exe/api/v1/auth',urlSearchParams)
        .subscribe((res:Response) => 
        {               
            const data = res.json();                                    
            let headers = new Headers({
                'OTCSTICKET': data['ticket']
            });

            let request_options = new RequestOptions({ headers:headers});

           return this.http.get("http://localhost/otcs/cs.exe/api/v1/nodes/16236/output",request_options)          
               .subscribe(data =>
               {    
                   const report = data.json();
                   this.result = report;
                   console.log(this.result);             
               },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);                
                }


       )});


   }
}
```

**App Component**

```
      import { Component } from '@angular/core';
      import { AuthenticationService } from './authNew.servive';
      import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
      import{Http, RequestOptions,Headers} from '@angular/http'
      import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
      import { URLSearchParams,Response } from '@angular/http';

      @Component({
                selector: 'app-root',
                templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
                 })

           export class AppComponent 
         {

             constructor(private authenticationservice:AuthenticationService)
              {

                this.authenticationservice.login().subscribe(res:Response =>
                  {
                    //somecode
                   }) ;

            }

         }
```

The Problem is when I am trying to subscribe in AppComponent, I get the below error:

[image]

I understand I am doing something really silly here. Also I tried to use map instead of subscribe in my service for both the POST and GET calls but in that case i get an error as sown below:

[image]

I was importing 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; when trying to use map and still I was getting the error, hence i thought about subscribing within the service itself but that isn't helping either. Please help me in understanding how can I get this sorted and get data from my service to be available in AppComponent.

Thanks !

Comment: Why are you subscribing in both the service *and* the component? You really only need to subscribe in the component.

Comment: okay then how shall i modify my service can you please help me in understanding that.

Comment: You should not use nested subscribes, use flattening operators instead (switchMap, concatMap or flatMap). The error comes because you have already subscribed to the service. You need to return an Observable from your service and then subscribe to it in the component.

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing twice, in the service and in the component.

You have in the official tutorial how should be managed this scenario:

[Tour of heroes http](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

The resume is that you should get the observable in your service

```
return this.http.get("http://localhost/otcs/cs.exe/api/v1/nodes/16236/output",request_options);
```

and manage the subscribe in the component:

```
this.authenticationservice.login().subscribe(res:Response =>
                  {
                    //somecode
                   }) ;
```